# Start a new line after 4th element in list

Tags: python, list, newline, fibonacci

I've written a code to print a Fibonacci sequence up to a certain value input by the user. I need the output to start a new line after every 4th element.

Here is my code:

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive number: \n"))
f1, f2 = 0, 1
count = 1
fibonacci = [f1]

while count < number:
        fn = f1 + f2
        f1 = f2
        f2 = fn
        fibonacci.append(f1)
        count += 1

print(fibonacci)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like adding a tag for the programming language used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not changing priginal `fibonacci` list, you can print your values like this.

Instead of

```
print(fibonacci)
```

you could use this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(fibonacci), 4):
     print(fibonacci[i:i+4])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))
def fabronic(n):
   if n<=1:
      return n
   else:
      return fabronic(n-1)+fabronic(n-2)
count,n=0,0
while n<number:
   print(fabronic(n),end=' ')
   count+=1
   if count==4:
      print()
      count=0
   n=n+1  
input=Enter a positive number: 15    
output=   
0 1 1 2   
3 5 8 13   
21 34 55 89   
144 233 377     

By using list  

n=0
mylist=[]
while n<number:
    mylist.append(fabronic(n))
    n=n+1
for item in range(0,len(mylist),4):
    print(mylist[item:item+4],sep=' ',end='\n')  
output=  
Enter a positive number: 15  
[0, 1, 1, 2]  
[3, 5, 8, 13]  
[21, 34, 55, 89]  
[144, 233, 377]
```

Answer (score -1):

You already have a counter so I guess what you want is that every time it reaches a multiple of 4, use print('\n')

Comment: Please provide OP with a complete working solution.  Since we ask those asking questions to provide a MRE, this seems only reasonable.